# IE: Can't submit form after selecting file programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, file-upload

I found that the only way to programmatically trigger 'Select File' dialog is by invoking click() function on the hidden input file control. 
Tried this in Chrome, works perfectly. in IE, Select File dialog is displayed, but the form can't be submitted after the file is selected. 
Here's the simplified code (input file is not hidden in this example):

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="myform" action="test.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="myfile" onchange="submit();"/>
<input type="button" value="Browse File" onclick="document.getElementById('myfile').click()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Looks pretty straightforward, can't see what IE doesn't like here...

Comment: IE security restrictions prevent this, because you can steal files from someone by guessing the path on their desktop and silently uploading it to your server.